# Логическая задача про животных Turbo Prolog

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

Задана база знаний «Животные»:
Живой - пес.
Рекс - собака.
Белка - кошка.
Быстрый - лошадь.
Живой - черный.
Белка - белая.
Рекс - рыжий.
Быстрый - белый.
Домашние животные - собака или кошка.
Животные - или лошадь, или домашние животные.
Том обладает тем, кто пес и нечерого цвета.
Мери обладает тем, кто или черного цвета, или лошадь.
Написать программу на Prolog и ответить на вопрос: Кем является Белка? Вывести всех животных белого цвета. Вывести клички всех домашних животных

Вот код но  яне могу понять как ответить на вопрос Кем является Белка?:

```
domains
    animal=symbol
predicates
    dog(animal)
    cat(animal)
    horse(animal)
    white(animal)
    black(animal)
    rufous(animal)
    animal_house(animal)
    animal_z(animal)
    tom_v(animal)
    meri_v(animal)

clauses
    dog(zhavii).
    dog(reksh).
    cat(bilka).
    white(shidkii).
    white(bilka).
    horse(shidkii).
    black(zhavii).
    rufous(reksh).
    animal_house(X):- cat(X).
    animal_house(X):- dog(X).
    animal_z(X):- horse(X).
    animal_z(X):- animal_house(X).
    tom_v(X) if dog(X) and not(black(X)).
    meri_v(X):- black(X).
    meri_v(X):- horse(X).
goal
    white(X) and
    write( "White animals: ",X) and nl,
    animal_house(X) and
    write( "Animals house: ",X) and nl.
```

Comment: что вас не устраивает в вашем коде?

Comment: write( "Animals house: ",X) and nl, здесь скорее всего ожидается точка, а не запятая